# How to apply jquery command to multiple divs?

Tags: jquery

Say I want to hide a few divs at once.

```
$("#something").click(function() {
  $("#one").hide();
  $("#two").hide();
  $("#three").hide();
});
```

How could I shorten the middle three lines to just one line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#one, #two, #three').hide();
```

or give them a class and hide them all at once

```
$('.class').hide();
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add a comma like this

```
$("#one, #two, #three").hide();
```

Answer (score 2):

Just comma separate them :)

```
$("#something").click(function() {
  $("#one, #two, #three").hide();
});
```